# Contruct a deterministic automata from a non-deterministic automata

Tags: automata

Here is a non deterministic finite automata:

[image]

Here is the deterministic finite automata I built from the above automata.

[image]

It seems the construction of the second automata is wrong. For me, this is perfectly fine. Where am I wrong?

Comment: One immediate problem is that you have no $b$ transition out of $\{1,2\}$ or out of $\{4\}$. (I have not checked all of the transitions.)

Comment: I have changed my question. I should be fine now. I think it is fine for $\{4\}$

Comment: *automata* is plural; *automaton* is singular

Comment: @Ulice: I just gave it a quick check, but it appears to be okay now.